# TouchableWithoutFeedback is throwing rendering error

Tags: react-native, touchablewithoutfeedback

I am developing a React Native application for learning purposes. Now I am using TouchableWithoutFeedback component to response the user interaction. But I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
class Events extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Events"
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Name 1",
          image_url: "https://www.vkguy.co.uk/images/slideshow/05.jpg"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Name 2",
          image_url: "https://www.vkguy.co.uk/images/slideshow/05.jpg"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Name 3",
          image_url: "https://www.vkguy.co.uk/images/slideshow/05.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  _handleLoadMore() {}

  renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
        
      }}>
        <View>
        <Card>
          <CardItem cardBody>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.image_url }}
              style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }}
            />
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left>
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
                <Text>12 Likes</Text>
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Button transparent>
                <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
                <Text>4 Comments</Text>
              </Button>
            </Body>
            <Right>
              <Text>11h ago</Text>
            </Right>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%" }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
          onEndReached={this._handleLoadMore}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Events;
```

When I click on the view, I got this error.

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

[image]

What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332

Comment: Is your `renderItem` function bound? Cannot see that in the provided code. Try binding the function by adding `this.renderItem=this.renderItem.bind(this)` in your constructor. Or simply convert the function to a fat-arrow function `()=>{}`.

Comment: Hi, Nishant, I added the binding in the constructor. But still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved this yet, but I just had the same issue.

Was an easy fix to a rather silly mistake.

```
import React, { Component, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
```

should have been

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with , maybe try Opening App.js file and modifying this line
class YourApp extends Component {
into
export default class YourApp extends Component<{}> {

Comment: Also , you maybe accidentally imported image from  native-base instead of importing it from react-native (it's a common mistake)

Comment: No it is not the issue. If I removed TouchableWithoutFeedback component, everything is working as expected.

Comment: maybe you should fill the ''onPress'' function with something?like just and alert?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your imports it's tough to say. If you're sure you're exporting your components, then it probably has to do with named vs default exports, or forgetting to export one of your components. Check to make sure if you're using a default export...

`export default ExampleComponent`

your import doesn't include brackets and looks like

`import ExampleComponent from '../../folder/file'`

Otherwise if you're using named exports like so...

`export const ExampleComponent = () => {`

your import includes brackets

`import { ExampleComponent } from '../../folder/file'`

Could help you more if you provide all of the involved components including the imports